# Python - Write in text mode to file opened in binary mode

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ftp, ftplib

I am asking this out of curiosity.

What I am doing:

- creating a temp file
- writing data from a Pandas dataframe to it by using `to_csv()`
- pushing the file to a FTP server

As the `tempfile` is opened in binary mode by default but the `to_csv()` method by default writes in text mode (which I need because I want to have UTF-8 as format) I am asking myself how you can write in text mode to a file opened in binary mode? I also need the binary format for the transfer to the FTP server.

What I did in detail:

I created a temp file like this:

```
fp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
```

As I unterstand from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) the file is opened in binary mode.

> tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', buffering=-1, encoding=None, newline=None, suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None, delete=True, *, errors=None)

Then I saved my dataframe to the temp file like this:

```
df.to_csv(fp.name)
fp.flush()
fp.seek(0)
```

Also the `to_csv()` method states in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) that you need to open the file with `newlines=''` which only works in text mode. So I couldn't set the `newline` argument using a file opened in binary mode.

> path_or_bufstr or file handle, default None
> File path or object, if None is provided the result is returned as a string. If a file object is passed it should be opened with `newline=''`, disabling universal newlines.

Then I used the `storbinary()` method from the ftplib to push the temp file to the FTP server. As I understand from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html) the method requires a binary file.

> FTP.storbinary(cmd, fp, blocksize=8192, callback=None, rest=None)
> Store a file in binary transfer mode. `cmd` should be an appropriate `STOR` command: `"STOR filename"`. `fp` is a file object (opened in binary mode) which is read until EOF using its `read()` method in blocks of size `blocksize` to provide the data to be stored. The `blocksize` argument defaults to 8192. `callback` is an optional single parameter callable that is called on each block of data after it is sent. `rest` means the same thing as in the transfercmd() method.

For completeness I afterwards closed and deleted the file like this:

```
fp.close()
os.unlink(fp.name)
```

I thought about opening the `tempfile` in `w+t` mode so that it matches the `to_csv()` method, which recommends opening the file with `newlines=''` which only works in text mode. Also I need to specify the UTF-8 format for the CSV file which only works in text mode. ftplib's `storbinary()` method requires a file opened in binary mode. (`storlines()` method also does) so this doesn't fit.

So I opened the file in binary mode, wrote to it in text mode and transferred it using binary mode. Everything works and the result looks like I want it to but I am a bit confused if I am doing it the right way. How does writing in text mode to a file opened in binary mode work? I kind of assumed I would have to open the file in text mode in order to write in text mode to it using `to_csv()`.

If anyone has a deeper knowledge about this and could clear up my confusion I would be very grateful. I don't like doing things not knowing why they work or if they should work haha.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite broad question. Just briefly. This is all mostly about line endings. That's basically the only distinction between the binary and text modes.

- If you "open" a file in the binary mode, all data are written exactly as they are. If you open a file in the text mode, newlines (`\n`) are converted according to the `newline` parameter.
- I do not think that Pandas need the file to be opened in the text mode. If you open the file in the binary mode, then whatever Pandas writes will end up physically in the file. See `line_terminatorstr` parameter of the [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).
- It's mostly the same with FTP. If you use `storbinary`, the file will be uploaded as is. If you use `storlines`, you let the FTP server convert the line endings.